# What does combination of "Function Key + Insert key" actually do?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

When I did it accidentally, it did like putting my windows machine to sleep

Is it what it does ?

Comment: what is related with programming in this question??

Comment: Generally speaking, Function Key combinations are specific to the manufacturer and/or the specific model of laptop.  They are usually indicated on the keyboard itself.

Comment: For dell laptops, this combination generally switches off the display. you do any movement in the track pad/ keyboard and your display starts working back.

Answer (score 0):

Function key is generally linked with OS/computer functions, so a comnbination of it and another key is usually a shortcut to some system function, which in this case is sleep-mode.

Answer (score 0):

In some computers, function+insert turns on numlock.

only fn does nothing, only insert pastes.

(Not an function key like f1, the fn key you see on your keyboard)